# Same footer line on every page

Tags: header-footer

Is there a way to place the same footer line on every page? Right now, I have a chapter called introduction and in my `introduction.tex` file I have specified a footer line that needs to be added. But the problem is, when the pdf file is being generated, the footer line I specified is only on the last page of the chapter. But I want it on every page in the chapter. Could someone please tell me how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Do you actually want a footnote (which usually elaborates on a superscripted reference in the main text), or a footer, which is usually a short piece of text that appears separate to the main text on each page?

Comment: @RichardTerrett I apologize for my ignorance for not knowing the difference between a footnote and a footer. But in this case I was actually referring to a footer.

Comment: I've edited the title and body of the question, changing all instances of "footnote" to "footer line", to better reflect the subject of the query.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To get a *footer line* on every page of the document, one could use the [fancyhdr](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) package, maybe along the lines of the following minimum working example (MWE):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}           % page number in "outer" position of footer line
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{Message of the day} % other info in "inner" position of footer line
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20] % generate about 4 pages of filler text
\end{document}
```

It's the "Message of the day" string that you'll want to change, for sure.

If the text in the footer line needs to be displayed in bold face and/or italics, you could do so by inserting the commands `\bfseries` and/or `\itshape` prior to the "Message of the day" string.

**Addendum** Two more points:

1. To get a *separate footer line for each chapter*, you should omit the command `\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{Message of the day}` from the preamble and, instead, issue the command `\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{Message for Chapter xx}` *immediately after* the respective `\chapter` command.
2. In the LaTeX `book` document class, the first page of a chapter uses the pagestyle "plain" (page number centered in footer line, no other header and/or footer information) even if the other pages follow a different pagestyle (such as "fancy"). If you want to display your chapter-specific footer lines on the first page of a chapter as well, you should issue the command `\thispagestyle{fancy}` *after* the respective `\chapter` command.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the footer is exactly the way I want it to be. With the help of the pdf link, I managed to add a fancy header as well - )

Comment: To whoever down-voted this answer on 2018-09-10, almost seven years after it was first posted (during which period the answer attracted 21 up-votes): Please let me know what it is about my answer that you found to be either wrong or otherwise sufficiently objectionable to incite a down-vote. I'm not being sarcastic; I simply wish to have a chance to address the supposed shortcoming(s) in my answer. Thanks in advance.