# Write the same footnote in each page

Tags: footnotes

I have to write the same footnote at the begin of the footnote space in each page, like this:

```
\footnotetext{Footnote space title that should go in each page}

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\footnotetext{first footnote}, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed fringilla eros vel sapien tristique tempor. Maecenas metus nisl, posuere ac quam nec, pretium rhoncus augue. Vivamus viverra nec leo vitae ornare. Praesent ac ultrices ante. Nulla sed risus et eros volutpat volutpat. Integer\footnotetext{second footnote} vitae nulla ut metus dictum imperdiet. Ut nisl neque, pellentesque blandit sapien nec, interdum imperdiet tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Donec cursus ex a leo eleifend, eget faucibus dolor vestibulum\footnotetext{third footnote}. Aenean feugiat aliquet diam nec lobortis. Fusce ullamcorper at ligula quis tincidunt.

\newpage
\footnotetext{Footnote space title that should go in each page}
Fusce sagittis volutpat augue eget viverra. Nam sollicitudin turpis at arcu consequat, vel vulputate leo egestas. Cras iaculis ex quam, sed viverra nulla gravida eu. Integer a tincidunt risus. In tellus ipsum, porttitor sed est vitae, pharetra\footnotetext{fourth footnote} sollicitudin dolor. Etiam sodales iaculis vestibulum. Nulla vestibulum diam sem, eu dignissim diam sodales eget. Proin a commodo ex, ac feugiat nisl.

\newpage
\footnotetext{Footnote space title that should go in each page}
Curabitur erat lacus, eleifend a nibh eu, efficitur ullamcorper purus. Donec vel felis risus. Etiam sit amet blandit odio. Aenean lobortis dignissim sapien, nec suscipit tellus condimentum et. Sed eget tortor sit amet erat ullamcorper euismod. Fusce\footnotetext{etc. etc} porta id lacus vel consectetur. Duis orci libero, eleifend in euismod at, viverra in ligula. Donec libero est, vehicula eget massa non, tincidunt posuere massa. Nullam tincidunt condimentum nibh, eget accumsan ligula pharetra at. Aenean et ex dictum, molestie neque nec\footnotetext{latest footnote}, porta nisl.
```

NOTE: the \newpage command is ONLY to show what I need, but I cannot insert it in each page.

Is it possible?

Comment: how about [same-footer-line-on-every-page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30339/same-footer-line-on-every-page) or [same-header-and-footer-for-every-page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109656/same-header-and-footer-for-every-page)

Comment: I've already seen the fancyhdr package but the \fancyfoot{} command modifies the page under the footnote space and I need to insert the text above this.

Comment: You can put in fancyfoot{} something like \raisebox[2ex]{\fnsymbol{\counterthatisone} Footnote-looking text.}

Comment: you want this in every page or every page that have footnote

Comment: Do you want that on *every* page or on every page which has footnotes on it?

Comment: In every page which has footnote on it.

Comment: @Doc then I guess a redefinition of `\footnoterule` might do (if you don't have footnotes in minipages…)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redefine `\footnoterule`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm,paperheight=8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % this is necessary

\makeatletter
% keep the original \footnoterule for minipage
\let\latex@footnoterule\footnoterule
\patchcmd{\endminipage}{\footnoterule}{\latex@footnoterule}{}{}
% redefine \footnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
  \vtop to 0pt{
    \vss
    \hrule \@width .4\columnwidth
    \vskip 3\p@
    \hbox{\footnotesize\itshape\fixedfootnotetext}
    \vskip 3\p@
    \hrule \@height \z@
  }
}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{4ex}
\makeatother

\newcommand\fixedfootnotetext{Footnote space title that should go in each page}


\begin{document}

a\footnote{First footnote} \lipsum[1-3]

c\footnote{Second footnote} \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The loading of `geometry` and `lipsum` is just for the example. Redefine `\fixedfootnotetext` to have what you'd like.

[image]

Comment: ok this work, but is there a way to limit the "footnote title" only in the first chapter?

Comment: @Doc Yes, of course. Make a new question.

Comment: [new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255162/write-a-footnote-title-in-each-page-limited-on-one-chapter)

open another question

Comment: ok I solved using this method and adding  this:  \providecommand\fixedfootnotetext{} \renewcommand\fixedfootnotetext{}
when i don't need more "footnote title"

Answer (score 0):

I did this before you qualified that you only wanted this on pages with footnotes.

Note that \FootnoteEnd is executed on the second page, but doesn't take effect until the third page.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\repeatfootnote}{\empty}
\newcommand{\againfootnote}%
{\ifx\repeatfootnote\empty\relax\else
   \footnotetext{\repeatfootnote}%
   \afterpage{\againfootnote}%
 \fi
}
\newcommand{\FootnoteStart}[1]% #1 = footnote text
{\def\repeatfootnote{#1}%
 \afterpage{\againfootnote}%
}
\newcommand{\FootnoteEnd}{\edef\repeatfootnote{\empty}}

\begin{document}
\footnotetext{First footnote}
\FootnoteStart{Footnote space title that should go in each page}
\lipsum[1-8]
\FootnoteEnd
\lipsum[9-16]

\end{document}
```

Comment: this work but only with a sentence, I have the footnote title that is composed by two minipages (I would like to write like a first line of table) and with the minipages inside the FootnoteStart latex doesn't compile :(

Comment: Okay, try it now.  (I changed \edef to \def.)