# Write a footnote title in each page limited on one chapter

Tags: footnotes

I have to write the same footnote in all pages of chapter 1. I have adopted this method but this work in all pages that has a footnote:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm,paperheight=8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % this is necessary

\makeatletter
% keep the original \footnoterule for minipage
\let\latex@footnoterule\footnoterule
\patchcmd{\endminipage}{\footnoterule}{\latex@footnoterule}{}{}
% redefine \footnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
 \vtop to 0pt{
 \vss
 \hrule \@width .4\columnwidth
 \vskip 3\p@
 \hbox{\footnotesize\itshape\fixedfootnotetext}
 \vskip 3\p@
 \hrule \@height \z@
}
}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{4ex}
\makeatother

\newcommand\fixedfootnotetext{Footnote space title that should go in each page}


\begin{document}

a\footnote{First footnote} \lipsum[1-3]

c\footnote{Second footnote} \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

is there a way to limit the "footnote title" only in one chapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revert the setting to the original one. In the code below you may want to set `\skipfootins` to 6ex instead of 4ex. Experiment on your own.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm,paperheight=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % this is necessary

\makeatletter
% keep the original \footnoterule for minipage
\let\latex@footnoterule\footnoterule
\patchcmd{\endminipage}{\footnoterule}{\latex@footnoterule}{}{}
% redefine \footnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
 \vtop to 0pt{
 \vss
 \hrule \@width .4\columnwidth
 \vskip 3\p@
 \hbox{\footnotesize\itshape\fixedfootnotetext}
 \vskip 3\p@
 \hrule \@height \z@
}
}
\newlength{\savedskipfootins}
\setlength{\savedskipfootins}{\skip\footins}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{4ex}

\newcommand{\revertfootnotes}{%
  \clearpage % just to be sure
  \let\footnoterule\latex@footnoterule
  \setlength{\skip\footins}{\savedskipfootins}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\fixedfootnotetext{Footnote space title that should go in each page}


\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Title}

a\footnote{First footnote} \lipsum[1-3]

c\footnote{Second footnote} \lipsum[2]

\revertfootnotes

\chapter{Another}

a\footnote{First footnote} \lipsum[1-3]

c\footnote{Second footnote} \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to switch back and forth between titled and untitled footnotes, you can define a new command for it.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm,paperheight=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % this is necessary

\makeatletter
% keep the original \footnoterule for minipage
\let\latex@footnoterule\footnoterule
\patchcmd{\endminipage}{\footnoterule}{\latex@footnoterule}{}{}
\newcommand{\title@footnoterule}{%
  \vtop to 0pt{
    \vss
    \hrule \@width .4\columnwidth
    \vskip 3\p@
    \hbox{\footnotesize\itshape\fixedfootnotetext}
    \vskip 3\p@
    \hrule \@height \z@
  }%
}
\newlength{\savedskipfootins}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\savedskipfootins}{\skip\footins}}
\AtBeginDocument{\titledfootnotes} % initialize to titled footnotes

\newcommand{\titledfootnotes}{%
  \clearpage % just to be sure
  \let\footnoterule\title@footnoterule
  \setlength{\skip\footins}{4ex}%
}
\newcommand{\revertfootnotes}{%
  \clearpage % just to be sure
  \let\footnoterule\latex@footnoterule
  \setlength{\skip\footins}{\savedskipfootins}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\fixedfootnotetext{Footnote space title that should go in each page}


\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Title}

a\footnote{First footnote} \lipsum[1-3]

c\footnote{Second footnote} \lipsum[2]

\revertfootnotes

\chapter{Another}

a\footnote{First footnote} \lipsum[1-3]

c\footnote{Second footnote} \lipsum[2]

\titledfootnotes

\chapter{Again}

a\footnote{First footnote} \lipsum[1-3]

c\footnote{Second footnote} \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: how can I enable and disable the "footnote title" on my own? I have tried to renew again the footnoterule command after the revertfootnotes command (obviously in the text not in the preamble) but it didn't work :(

Comment: @Doc Here it is. `;-)`

Comment: YEAH thanks! It's exactly what I needed! (be prepared...a new question is coming ;) ) XD

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do

\renewcommand{\fixedfootnotetext{}}

when you don't need anymore, or redefine it as something else?

Comment: YEAH this work! but I had to insert another command:

\providecommand\fixedfootnotetext{}
\renewcommand\fixedfootnotetext{}

or I get an error

Comment: You can only use \renewcommand to redefine a command that has already been defined; \providecommand is similar but works either with a new or existing command. So you may use          \providecommand{\fixedfootnotetext{}}
 in the preamble to make sure the \fixedfootnotetext command exists and then later use \renewcommand

Comment: I am so dumb...